# R Iterative substitution with for loop and if else

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm a new useR so please bear with me.

I have a data frame, `dfalpha`, with several variables and its corresponding values. Something similart to:

```
individual  variable    value
alpha   a   0.2
alpha   b   0.4
alpha   c   0.6
alpha   d   0.8
```

I have another data frame `dfbeta`, for other individual

```
individual  variable    value
beta    a   0.1
beta    b   0.8
beta    c   0.5
beta    d   0.3
```

I need to substitute alpha a value (0.2) for beta a value (0.1), then undo this substitution and substitute alpha b value (0.4) for beta b value (0.8). And so on for the rest.

I have tried:

```
for(i in 1:4){
  if (i = 1) {
    dfalpha$value[i] <- dfbeta$value[i] 
  } else {
    dfalpha$value[i] <- dfbeta$value[i]
    dfalpha$value[i-1] <- dfalphapermanent[i-1]
  } 
  print(dfalpha) 
}
```

I have a `dfalphapermant` data frame out of the loop for undoing the substitution. In order to check everything is OK, I print the results. 
I have been trying but it seems it doesn't work. I have checked the if and else statement but they seem to be correctly positioned.

PS: Sorry for the patchy style of programming, I am very new and self taught on this.

Comment: It is very unclear what you want to achieve. Surely, you don't only want to print.

Comment: Maybe you could just `merge` the two data sets to have both values in one?

Comment: well.. il you want ot design a program capable of doing things and undoing them just after, you might better apply for a political campaign! ;-) please explain better what you expect...

Comment: Sorry, this is just a step in a long thread needed to create waterfall charts out of some econometric analysis coefficients.
I need to substitute the value for one variable (e.g. variable a) in dfalpha with the value of variable a of dfbeta (e.g. so substitute 0.2 for 0.1 in this case). 
Then, I need to undo this substitution, and substitute the next variable (e.g. b). So substitute 0.4 (dfalpha variable b value) for 0.8 (dfbeta variable b value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have the statement `if (i = 1)`. `i=1` always evaluates to TRUE because it's assigning `1` to `i`.

You want `if (i == 1)`

Comment: Thanks for spotting this. Im sorry, I am very new to R and stack overflow is my only source of help!

Comment: No problem. A good debugging tip for this situation - build your code from the simplest framework up. For example, run `for(i in 1:4){if(i=1) print("i is one") else print("i is not one")}` and you'll see the error pretty quickly